# Check if User.isLoggedIn

Tags: authentication, download, magento-1.9

I have the following piece of code which I use to display a downloadable link only if the user is logged in. The code used to work.

After the user is logged in, the link tells me I still need to login. I expect it has to do with formkey.

How can I go about fixing this?

```php
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):  /*If user is not logged in*/ ?>
<?php $registerUrl = $this->getData('registerUrl'); /** generate your register URL*/ ?>
<div>
 <?php echo "<a href='$registerUrl'>Please login to download, gelieve eerst in te loggen, Bitte erst Anmelden </a>";  /*Ask user to Register*/ ?>
</div>

 <?php else: /*If user logged in*/ ?>
 <?php $downloadUrl = $this->getData('downloadUrl');/**generate your download URL */ ?>
<div>
 <?php echo "<a href='$downloadUrl'>Link</a>"; /* Allow user to download */ ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I added

```
<?php Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>
```

Just before

```
<?php if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):  /*If user is not logged in*/ ?>
```